# Loop in Python not giving output

Tags: python, loops

Can anyone see the error in this code? I think that it should print two1[i], but it prints nothing.

```
two1=[1,2,10,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
count = 0
i = 0
while count < 4:
    #if i == len(two1)-6: break
    #else:
        if abs(int(two1[i+2]) - int(two1[i+3]))>10 and abs(int(two1[i+4]) -abs(int(two1[i+5]))<10  
            print two1[i]
            count = count + 1
            i = i + 6
        if abs(int(two1[i+2]) - int(two1[i+3]))<10 and abs(int(two1[i+4]) -  abs(int(two1[i+5])) > 10:


            print two1[i]
            count = count + 1
            i = i + 6
        else:
            count = count + 1
            i = i + 6
```

Comment: No two adjacent numbers in the array have a difference greater than 10, which means neither print will run.

Comment: No error in this code, it does not print anything because it does not match the conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There aren't any elements in `two1` whose difference is bigger than 10. The maximum difference is `9` between `1` and `10` hence the condition:

```
abs(int(two1[i+2]) - int(two1[i+3]))>10
```

Is always false. This means that neither the first, nor the second `if` are executed, but the `else` is always executed.

Comment: I am getting "File "<string>", line 8
    if abs(int(two1[i+2]) - int(two1[i+3]))>10 and abs(int(two1[i+4]) -abs(int(two1[i+5]))<10:
                                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: When I run the code on the list I actually want to run it on, I get "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: When I run the code above in the terminal, I get "yntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>             print two1[i]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print two1[i]
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>             count = count + 1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    count = count + 1
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>             i = i + 6
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    i = i + 6
    ^ "

Comment: @BogusRoads Copy pasting the code in a terminal doesn't give any `SyntaxError` for me. I think you are putting some whitespace before it, breaking the indentation or something else.